# Is there a way to get inline text editing in UWP (like file rename in Windows Explorer)?

Tags: uwp, controls

Our app exposes a collection of objects to the user, displayed in a ListView. Each object has a set of descriptive strings associated with it. Currently, we use a DataTemplate that has a number of TextBlock controls arranged in a vertical StackPanel, one TextBlock per descriptive string. The top string is the Name of the object. We would like to offer the user the ability to edit the Name inline. Our behavioral model for this is Windows Explorer or Visual Studio, where you can rename a file in the file list control.

[image]

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this using UWP / WinUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could integrate `TextBox` with `TextBlock` that bind with same property, when you double click `TextBlock`, you could use [xaml behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to show the TextBox and hide TextBlock. Go back to previous state when text updated.

```
<Grid >
    <TextBox
        x:Name="Editor"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{x:Bind TextInfo, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="LostFocus">
                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Visibility"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Editor}"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Visibility"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DisplayLabel}"
                    Value="Visible" />
            </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="DisplayLabel"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{x:Bind TextInfo, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Visibility"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DisplayLabel}"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Visibility"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Editor}"
                    Value="Visible" />
            </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStyleGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="EditState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Editor.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="DisplayLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```